# Close the [art] gallery

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, synonym-request

Another day, another meta-tag:

[art](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/art)

> Art is the product or process of deliberately arranging items (often with symbolic significance) in a way that influences and affects one or more of the senses, emotions, and intellect.

Doesn't belong on any of the questions that would be asked here, as they'd be entirely too broad.

What complicates things a bit is that there are questions that pertain to the Android Runtime, or ART for short, buried in that tag.

So, I propose a burnination in two steps:

- Burninate the occurrences of [art](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/art) that are off-topic, and
- Synonymize [art](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/art) with [android-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-runtime) if any on topic questions pertaining to that remain.

---

As of 11 June 2015, the [art](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/art) tag is now only left with Android questions.  Could anyone here with some score in [android-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-runtime) synonimize the two?

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow, the go-to place to get your daily dose of puns.

Comment: Seems to be the trend now.  Beats having a drier title, in my opinion.

Comment: That's a good pun, Makoto. Thank you for your participation in the Great Pun War.

Comment: Let's admit it. The voting on tag burnination questions is based on the quality of the pun instead of whether the tag should actually be burninated. :)

Comment: I almost exclusively browse the [android] tag and I have seen a lot of question tagged with [art]. I never looked at the tag description and I always assumed that [art] was the tag for Android Runtime. In practice most people refer to the Android Runtime as ART. So [art] should definitely be a synonym of [android-runtime]. In fact I am shocked that [art] is supposed to mean something else.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Create ART Tag, without wiki->User Wants quick Tag Wiki Badge -> c/p description from Wikipedia->Chaos

Comment: Should I feel bad that there weren't many [ascii] + [art] questions?

Comment: Oh! What about the Algebraic Reconstruction Techniques then! :p

Comment: I believe you've found A Removable Tag there.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  Slow down there, tiger.  We may need to do another round of cleanup on some of those questions, but by and large that tag should be synonmized.

Comment: Looking at the tag description, the tag has nothing to do with [tag:android]. Also, not all questions it's linked to are about [tag:android], let alone [tag:android-runtime]. Since there's only 16 questions linked, I really don't see the point in keeping the tag. (Heck, I'd remove the tag manually, if people agree)

Comment: A handful could survive.  I'd help you out, but I'm out of votes and very, very thin on close/delete votes.

Comment: I mean we could just remove (edit) the tag from the questions, and let the cleanup script do the rest

Comment: I'm quite serious when a scalpel should be taken here as opposed to a hammer.  Some of these questions *do* relate to Android Runtime.  Don't let them fall to the wayside.

Comment: Then they should have the [tag:android-runtime] tag instead, not?

Comment: **That's the point.**  Two things here that I think you're missing:  there are questions which are tagged in error with art instead of android-runtime; this is because "art" in the technical parlance is presumed to mean the Android Runtime, and art would make **perfect sense** as a synonym to android-runtime.

Comment: My point is, that I don't think it's worth it synonymizing a tag that currently has _only_ 16 questions. Just replace the tag with what it shoul've been on the few questions that are actually about android-runtime, and remove the rest. Do we really need to synonymize a tag that's been used 16 times in the 4 years it's existed? The tag even had it's artistic meaning from the starts, meaning it was incorrectly added to android questions. The tag was never about android. You can't just change a tag's definition like that.

Comment: I'm retagging android-runtime questions and removing the [tag:art] tag from questions unrelated to ART. There's no point in keeping the [tag:art] tag around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've re-tagged the (16) questions that contained [art](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/art).

Some were about actually [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) / [android-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-runtime), thus incorrectly tagged [art](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/art), those were re-tagged [android-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-runtime) (only 8 of'm).

Others were about "art" projects, or had no relation to either the artistic or the Android version of "art". There, I've removed the tag, and close-voted a couple of them:

- [What coding projects are used to create art and beauty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169272)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903651 (About [android-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-runtime), but low quality)
- [What is the easiest way to assign a value to words in a txt file dependent on their frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682461)

(Close votes on those are welcome)

---

Since [art](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/art) is gone, we can declare it:

[image: tag burninated]

♫♩ Burninating the countryside ♪♬ burninating the peasants ♫♩ burninating all the peoples ♬♪ in the thatch roofed cottages! ♬♩

*Wicked dueling guitar-solos*.

> *This "Burninated" block was sponsored by <sub>(shamelessly stolen from)</sub> the ever mighty [Martijn Pieters ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)*